# Flutter Theme (dark & light)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am working on an application that contains two modes, Dark and Light Theme, I used extension to check between them as shown unfortunately.

**Extension to check theme mode**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension DarkMode on BuildContext {
  bool get isDarkMode {
    final brightness = MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness;
    return brightness == Brightness.dark;
  }
}
```

I also have a separate class that contains both Dark Theme and Light Theme

**App theme class**

```
class AppTheme {
  
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    // My light theme
  );
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    // My dark theme
  );

}
```

**In the MaterialApp I put these codes**

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        // ...
      ),
```

Now things work correctly when you change the mod from the phone system, the theme changes perfectly as shown below:

[image]

The `problem` now is when you select the theme, or rather when you put the Light theme, the theme does not work properly. I put an image:

Everything is supposed to change to a light theme, as in the previous video, but it does not happen

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
        //themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        // ...
      ),
```

[image]

I want to know what is wrong and how can I solve that problem so that everything works correctly when switching between each theme.

Comment: Did you spell light incorrectly in your code? otherwise that could be the bug

Comment: No, I made a typo, I just corrected it

Comment: Did you check what your extension is returing ?

Comment: Would you please try check on Theme.of(context).brightness instead of MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness In your DarkMode extension?

Comment: Your answer is correct my friend, you are amazing, thank you all MostafaSoliman, and Minato

Comment: You're welcome, I have added it as an answer, would you please mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check on `Theme.of(context).brightness` instead of `MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness` In your `DarkMode` extension